# How to send two strings through client to server using Socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

Here my code (sends only single String)

Client

```
Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",9999);    
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String msg;

PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

System.out.print("Enter the Msg : ");
msg = in.nextLine();

pr.print(msg);
```

Server

```
ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(9999);
Socket sock = ser.accept();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

String msg = br.readLine();

System.out.println("Received Msg : "+msg);
```

This Code Works Clearly. But I want to Send two strings through client to server.

Comment: Send another string the same way you did with the first one.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to send `Strings` as many times as you want, like a chat? If not, alfasin's comment should do the trick. 2 `readLine()` on the Server, and 2 `println()` on the Client

Comment: Use `pr.println(msg);` so that readLine can separate the strings.

Comment: Thks Dude. Its Works..... Thks for Answer......

Comment: Never forget to close the `Socket` as well once done.